# Ruby On Rails - Caching not loading new data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, serialization

I have a `post` model that `has_many :comments".

When deleting a `comment` from a `post`, refreshing the page will show still have the deleted `comment`.

Here are my `Serializer` files:

### Post Serializer

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes

has_many :comments
## In Post model: has_many :comments
end

## Comment Serializer ##
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

cached
delegate :cache_key, to: :object

attributes: #some attributes

end
```

Is there a way to notify `cache` that the `post` was modified(since one of its comments was `destroyed`).

Answer (score 1):

In `CommentSerializer` add `belongs_to :post, touch: true`.

`touch: true` will update column `updated_at` at `PostSerializer` table and expire cache.

Comment: I've already added the `touch` attribute to my models but it seems it didn't work...